# Поиск номера телефона в строке (Regex + сравнение)

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Доброго времени суток. Столкнулся с такой задачей:

Есть `phoneNumber`(номер телефона в международном формате без +) и `message` (обычное сообщение). Нужно проверить есть ли в `message` какой-либо номер телефона.

**Например:** *501234567*, *0501234567*, *74959741926*, *(050)1234567*, *(050)12-3-4-5-6-7*, и остальные все возможные варианты с пробелами, скобками и дефисами или часть номера.

Если он есть, то проверить совпадает ли он с `phoneNumber`. Если нет - удалить из строки. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это можно сделать с минимальными затратами? Заранее спасибо.

**Примеры `message`:**

```
string message = "Всем привет. Звоните на этот номер0501234567 и на этот 0221314156";
string message = "Всем привет. Звоните на этот номер 0(50)12-232312";
string message = "Всем привет. Звоните на этот номер +38050-123-456-7";
string message = "Всем привет. Звоните на этот номер 8050123456-7";
// и так далее
```

**`phoneNumber` выглядит так:**

```
string phoneNumber = "380509999999";
```

**P.S**: только нужно учитывать что пользователь мог ввести в `message` свой номер телефона с пробелами, скобками, дефисами или часть этого номера.

Comment: Примеры message бы помогли понять, как вам лучше быть. Именно message целиком, а не как там могут выглядкть номера внутри.

Comment: @tym32167, обновил сообщение

Comment: удаляете из строки все не цифры (или только выбранный набор допустимых разделителей, но в этом случае после удаления выделяете собственно подряд идущие цифры), потом проверяете длину, если короткая - пытаетесь дописать код. если начало с 8 пробуете дописать 3.

Comment: а на какую страну рассчитан поиск? Россия или вообще любой телефонный? ведь разница в количестве чисел имеется

Comment: @АлексейШиманский любой телефонный номер в международном формате

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы показали нам все варианты, то вот пример:

Проверка есть ли искомый номер в строкею Удаляем из строки все не-цифры, смотрим является ли номер подстрокой результата:

```
bool HasNumber (string message, string number)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(message)) return false;
    var str = new string(message.Where(c=>char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray());
    return str.Contains(number);
}
```

Удаление номера из строки. Идем от конца сообщения в начало, пока встретим что то, что может быть частью собщения, а не номера. Ну и берем построку.

```
string RemoveNumber(string message, string number)
{
    if (!HasNumber(message, number)) return message;

    for(var i =message.Length - 1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        var c = message[i];
        if (!char.IsDigit(c) && c!='+' && c!='-' && c!=' '&& c!='(' && c!=')')
        {
            return message.Substring(0, i + 1);
        }
    }

    return message;
}
```

Как проверить:

```
void Main()
{
    var messages = new[]{
    "Всем привет. Звоните на этот номер0501234567",
    "Всем привет. Звоните на этот номер 0(50)12-3-4-567",
    "Всем привет. Звоните на этот номер +38050-123-456-7",
    "Всем привет. Звоните на этот номер 8050123456-7"};

    var number = "0501234567";

    foreach(var message in messages)
    {
        var hasNumber = HasNumber(message, number);
        var removed = RemoveNumber(message, number);
        Console.WriteLine($"mesage:{message},\nnumber:{number},\nhasnumber:{hasNumber},\nremoved:{removed}\n");     
    }
}
```

Вывод программы:

```
mesage:Всем привет. Звоните на этот номер0501234567,
number:0501234567,
hasnumber:True,
removed:Всем привет. Звоните на этот номер

mesage:Всем привет. Звоните на этот номер 0(50)12-3-4-567,
number:0501234567,
hasnumber:True,
removed:Всем привет. Звоните на этот номер

mesage:Всем привет. Звоните на этот номер +38050-123-456-7,
number:0501234567,
hasnumber:True,
removed:Всем привет. Звоните на этот номер

mesage:Всем привет. Звоните на этот номер 8050123456-7,
number:0501234567,
hasnumber:True,
removed:Всем привет. Звоните на этот номер
```

Если требования\кейсы другие, дорабатывайте алгоритм под нужны. Необходимости в регулярках тут вроде нет.

Comment: Вы не так поняли. Мне нужно удалять все номера кроме номера пользователя.

Comment: Ну, какие вы мне дали примеры, такую я программу  написал :)